# How do I send a PIL generated PNG as an embed?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm using Python / Discord.py to code a Discord bot.

Just now I figured out how to create an image out of several pngs using `PIL` and was able to send it perfectly fine using:

```py
background.save("final.png")
await ctx.send(file=discord.File("final.png"))
```

but since I didn't want the image to be saved every time I did my research and ended up with this using `BytesIO`:

```py
background.save(bytes,format='PNG')
bytes.seek(0)
await ctx.send(file=discord.File(bytes,filename="final.png"))
```

It still works but I wanted to use the final image (final.png) as an image in an embed and I can't get it to work. Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`set_image`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=set_image#discord.Embed.set_image) to include image in embed:

```py
# Creating image
background.save(bytes,format='PNG')
bytes.seek(0)

# Creating embed
embed = discord.Embed()
embed.set_image(url="attachment://final.png")

# Sending embed with img
await ctx.send(file=discord.File(bytes,filename="final.png"), embed=embed))
```